# SUM a range based on the last cell on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table as below. Now I'd like to SUM all the values from **B1** to the cell which matches with the value of column A that I input. Ex: If I input **c**, it will SUM from **B1** to **B3**.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 |
| 2 | b | 4 |
| 3 | c | 7 |
| 4 | d | 1 |
| 5 | h | 5 |
| 6 | z | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values in `A` are unique or you want sum to first found value it is enought:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,1):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C1,A:A,0)))
```

or if not unique and you want sum to last value:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,1):INDEX(B:B,LOOKUP(99^99,ROW(A:A)/--(A:A=C1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Test and this work. Yes, the key is unique.

Answer (score 1):

if C1 = `c` try in D1:

```
=INDEX(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(MATCH(C1, A:A, 0), 2)&":"&
 ADDRESS(MAX(FILTER(ROW(A:A), A:A=C1)), 2) )))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(1, 2)&":"&
 ADDRESS(MAX(FILTER(ROW(A:A), A:A=C1)), 2) )))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried but it seems incorrect: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nlZrfoWhJ6Tkxh_8gSa8bFvQN_wuiDBr92h4LWrRr0E/edit#gid=1357660258

Comment: @JOY answer updated